# Attribute from class iteration return object instead of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple `div`s that have an attribute on my page e.g.:

```
<div class="followCallout" id="follow_123" data-follow-id="123">
    WHATEVER
</div>
....
<div class="followCallout" id="follow_456" data-follow-id="456">
    WHATEVER
</div>
```

With a timer i loop through these divs and make an ajax call for each, to see if sth has changed:

```
function checkFollows() {
var t = setTimeout(checkFollows, 5000);

$('.followCallout').each(function(){
    var $that = $(this);
    var $id = $that.attr('data-follow-id');
    var $url = $('#ajax-route-check-follow').val();
    console.log($id); //THIS RETURN 123 etc...
    $.ajax({
        url: $url,
        data: {
            id: $id
        },
        type: "get",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (err) {

        },
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
  })
}
```

The `$url` is from here `<input type="hidden" id="ajax-route-check-follow" value="/cCRM/web/app_dev.php/admin/_ajax/_checkFollow" />`

However, the URL I'm sending looks like this:

`http://localhost/cCRM/web/app_dev.php/admin/_ajax/_checkFollow?[object%20Object]&_=1497624513190`

So instead of `checkFollow?id=123` it gives me `checkFollow?[object%20Object]` so I assume sth is wrong with my ajax call? I am using the exact same call (w/o the $.each, only single calls though) on other parts as well. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You do `var $url = $('#ajax-route-check-follow').val();` that can't be correct. You need to build the URL for each div. The value in `$('#ajax-route-check-follow').val();` is already bad. You get `[object Object]` when convert an object to a string, so: `"foo" + {} + "bar"` gives `"foo[object Object]bar"`. The `%20` is because the string gets URL encoded. That's probably a good thing.

Comment: I use symfony3, so I generate an url in my twig template and get the url with that in javascript as I don't know how to get twig vars in javascript (different story). The `val` of `#ajax-route-check-follow` is `/cCRM/web/app_dev.php/admin/_ajax/_checkFollow` so there shouldn't be anything wrong with it? I can hardcode that as well, same output...

Comment: Just a little side note: the naming convention you're using, prefixing $ to the variable name, should be used for jQuery objects. $that makes sense, because it's a jQuery object representing an element. But $url and $id aren't jQuery objects, they're primitive values - they could also be objects, but the idea doesn't change - if you want to go down that road I'd suggest you use the $ prefix only if the variable referes to a jquery'ed element